# Differentiate function with respect to matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I need to differentiate the following function:
$$f(\Sigma)=-\frac{1}{2}\log|\Sigma|+-\sum_i C_i\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mu_i^2}{1+\Sigma_{ii}}\right)$$

to find, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma}$. The first term is a standard result. However its the sum of exponential terms that I'm unsure of. Treat $\mu_i, C_i$ to be constants and $\Sigma_{ii}$ are the diagonal terms in $\Sigma$.

I was thinking rewrite the second term as trace of $EC$ where $E$'s diagonal terms containing the exponential terms and $C$ is a diagonal matrix containing the $C_i$'s. <- just a suggestion, not sure if it will lead to a solution.

Comment: Compute the derivative of $\Sigma \mapsto \Sigma_{ii}$ and for $t \mapsto e^{-{1 \over 2} { \mu_i^2 \over 1 + t}}$.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do but, what is the derivative of $\Sigma$ wrt $\Sigma_{ii}$. Is it just the identity matrix?

Comment: You want the derivative of $\Sigma_{ii}$ with respect to $\Sigma$, not the other way around.

Comment: Whoops, sorry you're right

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the function $f_{ii}(\Delta) = [\Delta]_{ii}$ can be computed by noting that $f_{ii}$ is linear and hence is its own derivative, that is
$Df_{ii}(\Delta)(H) = f_{ii}(H) = [H]_{ii} = \operatorname{tr} (E^{ii} H)$.

The derivative of $g(t) = e^{-{1 \over 2} { \mu_i^2 \over 1 + t}}$ is given by
$g'(t) = {\mu_i^2 \over 2(1+t)^2 }e^{-{1 \over 2} { \mu_i^2 \over 1 + t}} $.

Hence the chain rule gives
$D (g \circ f_{ii})(\Sigma)(H) = Dg(f_{ii}(\Sigma))(Df_{ii}(\Sigma)(H)) = 
{\mu_i^2 \over 2(1+\operatorname{tr} (E^{ii} \Sigma))^2 }e^{-{1 \over 2} { \mu_i^2 \over 1 + \operatorname{tr} (E^{ii} \Sigma)}} \operatorname{tr} (E^{ii} H)$.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand the notation completely. If $f_{ii}(\delta)=\delta$ isn't the derivative just one? Also not sure what $E$ is. I'm guessing what you meant to say is that the off diagonals are all zero and the diagonal elements are ${\mu_i^2 \over 2(1+\Sigma_{ii})^2 }e^{-{1 \over 2} { \mu_i^2 \over 1 + \Sigma_{ii}}}$

Comment: No, the function $f_{ii}$ takes a matrix and returns the $ii$ element, so the derivative can't be just one. The matrix $E_{ii}$ is zero except for a one at the $ii$ place. A notationally convenient way of expressing such derivatives is with the trace.

Comment: Note that the derivative is a map $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$ if you prefer), so in general it doesn't have a 'nice' representation as multiplication by a matrix.

Comment: I didn't edit it, just needed to copy one part of your equations, for my question

Comment: :-) Bad timing on my part!

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand this. Sorry :( . First I'm trying to differentiate $f(\Sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^m  \exp(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mu_i^2}{1+\Sigma_{ii}})$ wrt $\Sigma$. This should surely give me an $N\times N$ matrix where the off diagonal elements are zero (since off diagonals do not affect the answer). Secondly how is derivative of $f(\Sigma)=\Sigma_{ii}$ itself? I've only heard of this happening with exponentials. In this step are you still referring wrt $\Sigma$ or $\Sigma_{ii}$. Finally isn't $tr(E_{ii}\Sigma_{ii})=\Sigma_{ii}$? Again apologies for my ignorance

Comment: First, I apologise for some abominable notation, I have replaced the $E_{ii}$ by $E^{ii}$ (each is a $n \times n$ matrix). I have removed the incorrect indices from the traces. I will address other questions subsequently.

Comment: In terms of my symbols and your $f$ from your last comment, $f = g \circ f_{ii}$, so we can use the chain rule to compute the derivative, which is what I have done above. The function $f$ has the form $f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$, so we expect that $Df(\Sigma):\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$. That is, $Df(\Sigma)$ is a linear map from the space of matrices to a scalar. The value $Df(\Sigma)(E^{ij})$ will give ${\partial f(\Sigma) \over \partial [\Sigma]_{ij}}$ if you will pardon he notation.

Comment: If you take the linear function $\phi(t) = \alpha t$, then you have $D \phi(t)(\delta) = \phi(\delta)$. This is notationally cumbersome on one dimension, but becomes a convenient 'safety' net when computing matrix derivatives.

Comment: If you have $\eta(t) = e^t$, then $D\eta(t)(\delta) = \eta(t) \delta$, or more typically, we write $D\eta(t) = \eta(t)$. In the linear case above, $D \phi(t) = \alpha$. When I wrote 'is its own derivative', I meant that $D f_{ii}(\Sigma)(\Delta) = f_{ii}(\Delta)$. I hope you see the differences and similarities. The issue with derivatives of functionals with respect to matrices is that there often is no 'nice' way of writing the derivative operator as a simple matrix product ($f_{ii}$ being a case in point).

Comment: And last, because of my earlier mistypes, I should have had $\operatorname{tr}(E^{ii} H)$ which is just $[H]_{ii}$, the $ii$ element of $H$. I must have had index frenzy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16121/discussion-between-sachin-ruk-and-copper-hat).

Comment: Not sure what the protocol is for this, but I am waiting in the chat room...